# How can I specify the exact number of digits in a number field contact form 7 WP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

**In Contact Form 7 - Wordpress**

How can I specify the exact number of digits in a number field contact form 7 WP?

Exact 9 length number validation.

Answer (score 0):

Two-fold, validation in the HTML, and validation on the form submission.

HTML

```
<input name="numbers" type="text" maxlength="9" size="20" pattern="^\d{9}$" placeholder="9 digits only" />
```

This limits the input to 9 characters, allows a pattern to match 9 digits only that will turn the input area red if incorrect, and adds placeholder text to warn the user.

JavaScript

For an example, this uses a simple button to validate the input prior to the form submission:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', formHandler, false);

function formHandler(e) {

  // Don't submit the form yet
  e.preventDefault();

  // Grab the form
  const form = document.forms[0];

  // Use the same regex as in the HTML to test the input value
  if (/^\d{9}$/.test(form.numbers.value)) {
    console.log('OK') // form.submit() ?
  } else {
    console.log('Fail')
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w0fenbbn/17/)**